# Parallax effect using GPU Acceleration

Tags: javascript, css

i'm trying to detect the scroll function and then pass the animation on to CSS so it can use hardware acceleration.

[See my test here](http://martynleeball.com/test/), will this be using hardware acceleration? I don't think it would be as JavaScript is still applying the values. Is there a way I could use keyframes to do the animations?

Answer (score 0):

Open Google Chrome's internal Task Manager. If there is a process titled GPU Process, then that means Chrome is using hardware/GPU acceleration in order to display/render a particular page.

Comment: It did have, I ended the process and then reloaded the page but it didn't appear again. However this page also doesn't make it appear and this should use hardware acceleration: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/